# Get single value from JSON object

Tags: javascript

I am using Google Maps API with jQuery getJSON:

```
$.getJSON(requestUrl, function(data) {
        var distance = //need to parse value from 'data' object here
    });
```

`data` object's structure is like this: (example)

[image]

I need to set my variable `distance` to `225 mi` in this case

Comment: Can you please replace the image with code? It is much easier for people to try and reconstruct your issue copying and pasting code, rather than reading it from an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.getJSON(requestUrl, function(data) {
    var distance = data.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
});
```

Pretty simple, but I do want to know if you'll ever get more then one row or element from your function?

Comment: I get "Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined" @DogPawHat

Comment: can you do a `console.log(data)` and tell me what that gets you?

Comment: sorry, it was my mistake, had some issues with my request url, fixed them and now your code works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
data.rows.forEach(function(value){ 
    value.elements.forEach(function(childValue) {
      console.log(childValue.distance.text);
    });
});
```

The above nested `forEach` should get you the distance value.

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = JSON.parse(data);
distance= json["rows"]["elements"]["distance"]["text"];
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The getJSON function will return data alreay parsed into a Javascript object.