# Get array data from an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, pdf

I have an array inside an object as below:

```
[
{ "id": 244, "title": "myBook.pdf", "author": "Kevin"},
{ "id": 370, "title": "Bookpress.pdf", "author": "Justin"},
{ "id": 433, "title": "Uptown.pdf", "author": "David"},
]
```

How can I get all the data of all title data? Data required is:
myBook.pdf, Bookpress.pdf, Uptown.pdf

Comment: Unless you tried, we are not gonna help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get single value from JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37570568/get-single-value-from-json-object)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using lodash, you can simply do this

```
var data = [
  { "id": 244, "title": "myBook.pdf", "author": "Kevin"},
  { "id": 370, "title": "Bookpress.pdf", "author": "Justin"},
  { "id": 433, "title": "Uptown.pdf", "author": "David"},
]

var result = _(data).map("title").value();
```

Gives you

```
result
(3) ["myBook.pdf", "Bookpress.pdf", "Uptown.pdf"]
```

But since this sounds like is an assignment question, you should try to do this by yourself without libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [`Array#map`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwic3tXn-9rVAhXDqI8KHUXoD2QQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap&usg=AFQjCNHaY16WQvsRJFKI1AN9YJUvUNjsCg) function .use `join(',')` function for applying comma

```js
var arr = [
{ "id": 244, "title": "myBook.pdf", "author": "Kevin"},
{ "id": 370, "title": "Bookpress.pdf", "author": "Justin"},
{ "id": 433, "title": "Uptown.pdf", "author": "David"},
]

console.log(arr.map(a=> a.title))
console.log(arr.map(a=> a.title).join(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop to loop through the array and use javascript object notation to fetch the desired object property and append that into the html or use in whatever way that you like.

```js
var arr =[
{ "id": 244, "title": "myBook.pdf", "author": "Kevin"},
{ "id": 370, "title": "Bookpress.pdf", "author": "Justin"},
{ "id": 433, "title": "Uptown.pdf", "author": "David"},
]

for (var i =0;i < arr.length;i++){

var el = document.getElementById("demo");
el.innerHTML += arr[i].title
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">
</div>
```