# Convert JSON object to array using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I have a jQuery ajax request which returns data in json format, how can we convert it and push in to an array. TIA.

```
[{"Day":"Nov 03","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":2,"Restaurant":null},
{"Day":"Nov 06","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":1,"Restaurant":1},
{"Day":"Nov 07","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":null,"Restaurant":1},
{"Day":"Nov 08","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":2,"Restaurant":null},
{"Day":"Nov 09","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":4,"Restaurant":null},
{"Day":"Nov 10","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":3,"Restaurant":null},
{"Day":"Nov 11","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":4,"Restaurant":null},
{"Day":"Nov 13","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":4,"Restaurant":1},
{"Day":"Nov 14","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":2,"Restaurant":1},
{"Day":"Nov 15","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":5,"Restaurant":null},
{"Day":"Nov 16","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":5,"Restaurant":null},
{"Day":"Oct 30","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":null,"Restaurant":2},
{"Day":"Oct 31","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":2,"Restaurant":3}]
```

Desired output :-

```
    [
      ['Day', 'Saavor Kitchen', 'Home Kitchen', 'Restaurant '],
      ['Nov 03',  1000,      400, 50],
      ['Nov 04',  1170,      460, 90],
      ['Nov 05',  660,       1120, 58],
      ['Nov 06',  1030,      540, 88]
    ]
```

Comment: Why do you need so strange conversion?

Comment: i need it to for google charts...

Comment: Well, so it is not enough clear where do you expect to get years and other data. Which fields need to be converted to the desired array elements

Comment: Please visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37570568/get-single-value-from-json-object) , it looks same

Comment: Where does `['2004',  1000,      400, 50]` come from?!!

Comment: thats just an example @MysterX, I have edited question, pl have a look again..

Comment: thats just an example @chsdk, it can be any number based on json

Comment: @SunilChaudhary provide valid Array object for better answers

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service, but a problem-solving one. We're happy to help you reach a solution but you need to do some research or write an initial version first.

Comment: thanks all for for your time and support..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like below  (using [.map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) and [.unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)):-

```js
var json = '[{"Day":"Nov 03","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":2,"Restaurant":null},{"Day":"Nov 06","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":1,"Restaurant":1},{"Day":"Nov 07","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":null,"Restaurant":1},{"Day":"Nov 08","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":2,"Restaurant":null},{"Day":"Nov 09","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":4,"Restaurant":null},{"Day":"Nov 10","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":3,"Restaurant":null},{"Day":"Nov 11","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":4,"Restaurant":null},{"Day":"Nov 13","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":4,"Restaurant":1},{"Day":"Nov 14","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":2,"Restaurant":1},{"Day":"Nov 15","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":5,"Restaurant":null},{"Day":"Nov 16","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":5,"Restaurant":null},{"Day":"Oct 30","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":null,"Restaurant":2},{"Day":"Oct 31","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":2,"Restaurant":3}]';

var columns = ['Day', 'Saavor Kitchen', 'Home Kitchen', 'Restaurant'];

var result = JSON.parse(json).map(function(obj) {
  return columns.map(function(key) {
    return obj[key];
  });
});
result.unshift(columns);
console.log(result);
console.log(Object.keys($.parseJSON(json)[0]));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

***To get keys dynamically:-***

```
console.log(Object.keys($.parseJSON(json)[0]));
```

Since you already used `dataType:'json'` in your ajax code, so do:-

```
console.log(Object.keys(json[0]));
```

Comment: one more thing can we get key name dynamically in this case like 'Day', 'Saavor Kitchen', 'Home Kitchen', 'Restaurant' bcoz these are dynamic and could be change in different scenarios..

Comment: @SunilChaudhary  i have added that solution also in my answer. Please check

Answer (score 5):

A simple combination of **[`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)** with an **[`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** will do the trick here:

```
var res = arr.map(function(item) {
  return Object.values(item);
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var arr = [{
    "Day": "Nov 03",
    "Saavor Kitchen": null,
    "Home Kitchen": 2,
    "Restaurant": null
  },
  {
    "Day": "Nov 06",
    "Saavor Kitchen": null,
    "Home Kitchen": 1,
    "Restaurant": 1
  },
  {
    "Day": "Nov 07",
    "Saavor Kitchen": null,
    "Home Kitchen": null,
    "Restaurant": 1
  },
  {
    "Day": "Nov 08",
    "Saavor Kitchen": null,
    "Home Kitchen": 2,
    "Restaurant": null
  },
  {
    "Day": "Nov 09",
    "Saavor Kitchen": null,
    "Home Kitchen": 4,
    "Restaurant": null
  },
  {
    "Day": "Nov 10",
    "Saavor Kitchen": null,
    "Home Kitchen": 3,
    "Restaurant": null
  },
  {
    "Day": "Nov 11",
    "Saavor Kitchen": null,
    "Home Kitchen": 4,
    "Restaurant": null
  },
  {
    "Day": "Nov 13",
    "Saavor Kitchen": null,
    "Home Kitchen": 4,
    "Restaurant": 1
  },
  {
    "Day": "Nov 14",
    "Saavor Kitchen": null,
    "Home Kitchen": 2,
    "Restaurant": 1
  },
  {
    "Day": "Nov 15",
    "Saavor Kitchen": null,
    "Home Kitchen": 5,
    "Restaurant": null
  },
  {
    "Day": "Nov 16",
    "Saavor Kitchen": null,
    "Home Kitchen": 5,
    "Restaurant": null
  },
  {
    "Day": "Oct 30",
    "Saavor Kitchen": null,
    "Home Kitchen": null,
    "Restaurant": 2
  },
  {
    "Day": "Oct 31",
    "Saavor Kitchen": null,
    "Home Kitchen": 2,
    "Restaurant": 3
  }
];

var res = arr.map(function(item) {
  return Object.values(item);
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an array of keys (the header) to use as the 1st row, and to get the values from the objects.

[Parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) the json, and iterate it with [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). On each iteration, map the array of keys, and extract the values from the object.

[Concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) the keys array as the 1st array.

```js
var json = '[{"Day":"Nov 03","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":2,"Restaurant":null},{"Day":"Nov 06","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":1,"Restaurant":1},{"Day":"Nov 07","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":null,"Restaurant":1},{"Day":"Nov 08","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":2,"Restaurant":null},{"Day":"Nov 09","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":4,"Restaurant":null},{"Day":"Nov 10","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":3,"Restaurant":null},{"Day":"Nov 11","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":4,"Restaurant":null},{"Day":"Nov 13","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":4,"Restaurant":1},{"Day":"Nov 14","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":2,"Restaurant":1},{"Day":"Nov 15","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":5,"Restaurant":null},{"Day":"Nov 16","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":5,"Restaurant":null},{"Day":"Oct 30","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":null,"Restaurant":2},{"Day":"Oct 31","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":2,"Restaurant":3}]';

var keys = ['Day', 'Saavor Kitchen', 'Home Kitchen', 'Restaurant'];
var result = keys.concat(JSON.parse(json).map(function(o) {
  return keys.map(function(key) {
    return o[key];
  });
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let res = [{"Day":"Nov 03","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":2,"Restaurant":null},{"Day":"Nov 06","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":1,"Restaurant":1},{"Day":"Nov 07","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":null,"Restaurant":1},{"Day":"Nov 08","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":2,"Restaurant":null},{"Day":"Nov 09","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":4,"Restaurant":null},{"Day":"Nov 10","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":3,"Restaurant":null},{"Day":"Nov 11","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":4,"Restaurant":null},{"Day":"Nov 13","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":4,"Restaurant":1},{"Day":"Nov 14","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":2,"Restaurant":1},{"Day":"Nov 15","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":5,"Restaurant":null},{"Day":"Nov 16","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":5,"Restaurant":null},{"Day":"Oct 30","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":null,"Restaurant":2},{"Day":"Oct 31","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":2,"Restaurant":3}];

//console.log((res))
let keys = [];
let day = [];
let saavor = [];
let homeKitch = [];
let restaurant = [];
let allData = [];

res.map((obj) => {
  if (keys.length ==0)  keys.push(Object.keys(obj))
  day.push(obj["Day"]);
  saavor.push(obj["Saavor Kitchen"]);
  homeKitch.push(obj["Home Kitchen"]);
  restaurant.push(obj["Restaurant"]);
})

allData[0] = keys;
allData.push(day);
allData.push(saavor);
allData.push(homeKitch);
allData.push(restaurant);

console.log(allData)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var json = '[{"Day":"Nov 03","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":2,"Restaurant":null},{"Day":"Nov 06","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":1,"Restaurant":1},{"Day":"Nov 07","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":null,"Restaurant":1},{"Day":"Nov 08","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":2,"Restaurant":null},{"Day":"Nov 09","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":4,"Restaurant":null},{"Day":"Nov 10","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":3,"Restaurant":null},{"Day":"Nov 11","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":4,"Restaurant":null},{"Day":"Nov 13","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":4,"Restaurant":1},{"Day":"Nov 14","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":2,"Restaurant":1},{"Day":"Nov 15","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":5,"Restaurant":null},{"Day":"Nov 16","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":5,"Restaurant":null},{"Day":"Oct 30","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":null,"Restaurant":2},{"Day":"Oct 31","Saavor Kitchen":null,"Home Kitchen":2,"Restaurant":3}]';

    $.each($.parseJSON(json), function(idx, obj) {
      $("#demo").html(obj.Day);
    });
```